# How can it be demonstrated that locally $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ is the effective field theory till $10^{-15} m $?

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model

How can it be demonstrated that locally  $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ is the effective field theory till $10^{-15} m $?

Comment: Are you asking whether the effective field theory of the SM could have viable competitors with a different symmetry structure at distances longer than the size of hadrons?

Comment: No, I am asking how it is demonstrated that standard model is an effective field theory, when you modifying if neccesary to account the GR errors, that normally is not neccesary at atomic scales, because gravitation is irrelevant, but it is neccesary to demonstrate that it is really an EFT

Comment: We are not communicating. ***All  features***  of the SM gauge theory have experimental consequences at distances over a fermi that have been brilliantly and unexceptionally   confirmed by *all* experiments in the last 45 years. This is what the PDG is all about, by and large. I have no clue why you are discussing gravity. There is no other viable theory adequate to describe that length domain. In fact, the model has been verified down to distances five orders of magnitude shorter than that.

Answer (score 1):

The [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-standard-model.pdf), last section, reminds you the SM is unchallenged by any theory from astronomical distances all the way down to 
$$
10^{-23} ~m, 
$$
and nothing is known for sure at shorter distances. It took over 45-55 years to settle that, in hundreds of experiments. There is no facile "demonstration". More importantly, there is no serious compelling competition, so far.

Comment: Well, but then, what other options will it be possible? I am not saying of course that nowadays we cannot use SM. It is the best option, but then it is a "bayesian" option. It has no intuitive (no alternative) postulates, like GR or QFT

Comment: Not anymore. Half a century did it.....  An elaborate sudoku puzzle fit perfectly in the standard model: It is an ad hoc solution. They tried all kinds of groups for the strong group, and certainly for the weak group (remember the Georgi-Glashow model?), but the present picture triumphed. If you are looking for an elegance/logically-compelling/beauty-driven justification for the SM you are really *barking up the wrong tree*. As the SM was triumphing in the last half century, dozens of aspirants to a grand theological vision for it failed spectacularly.

Comment: In PDG, it is said "The result in Eq. (10.56) is 2.0σabove the SM expectation,ρ0= 1. It canbe used to constrain higher-dimensional Higgs representations to have vacuum expectationvalues of less than a few percent of those of the doublet". 2.0 times the standard deviation of the SM. And in the other  equation I find no comment. 2,0 times the SD in the experiments that the SM predictions is a very bad result for the fiability of the SM. Why do you say that then it is the best model?

Comment: Mayebe there is no alternative theory, but the predictions are very bad, anyway. It is used in a "bayesian" sense the standard model. I am treating now that but strong and weak interactions, electromagnetism have better predictions than SM, because anyway it is at scales very little, in theory. Because nuclear reactions, sadly are known that have terrible macroscopic effects, I can´t understand, for example if electromagnetism is effective at atom size, why are there macroscopic effects for nuclear forces, more than bounding neutrons and protons in nucleus. It is another thing without explain

Comment: If you have monitored this "but re we sure?" game for 50 years and watched it fall flat on its face again and again, and again, you've learned to expect these "tensions", giving work to an army of ambulance chasers, are not reliable. By the time they go away, thousands of scientist-hours have been wasted, and no clear alternatives have survived.  But, if it is unreasonable hope you are pining for...

Comment: But what about in the double standard deviation. Don´t you consider it important? If it was less than the SD in the SM it would be inquiestionable its predictions, but in this case. I was reading in arxiv.org about that SM was an EFT. In this preprint, the SM is an EFT https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08945.pdf till 3 TeV, it is $ 10^{-6 } J, it is a very low energy, for explain electrons in an atom, chemistry, etc...is good, but to discard other forces in macroscopic scales is not useful. How can we know that at l laboratory distance scales we can not consider another force than the 4 of the SM?

Comment: 2σ are rarely truly  2σ; they are almost always not statistical errors, but rather loose guesswork systematics in disguise. This is why and how they constantly disappear if you wait long enough. The SM model has been triumphing, unassailable, for 50 years. One tries to overthrow it at one's own risk--assuming it would be acknowledged as risk!

Comment: I don´t understand the reason why σ real is overstimated, ¿could you explain me? Thank you